# iterating using optional completion handler calling itself, wont complete second time around

Tags: swift, completionhandler

I get this error:

> Value of optional type '((RestTime) -> ())?' must be unwrapped to a value of type '(RestTime) -> ()'

I call function from VC:

```
        let calculateSegmentDirections = CalculateSegmentDirections(locationManager: locationManager)
        calculateSegmentDirections.calculateSegmentDirections(index, time: time, routes: routes, loc: loc) { restTime in
                print("4")

        }




    func calculateSegmentDirections(_ index: Int, time: TimeInterval, routes: [MKRoute], loc: LocationModel, completion: ((_ restTime: RestTime) -> ())?) {
            print("1")
            if let routeResponse = response?.routes {
            print("2")
                    self.calculateSegmentDirections(index+1, time: timeVar, routes: routesVar, loc: restLocation, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    let restTime = RestTime(objectID: restLocation.objectID, time: timeVar, routes: routesVar)
                    print("3")
                    completion(restTime)
                }
    }
```

The function in its full form, is called from the VC, then iterates over itself to create a route from MKdirections. My question is, can i use an optional completion handler in this way?

the console prints 1, 2, 1, 3 like expected, but then doesnt call the completion. 4 is never fired. completion = nil, so when i unwrap with if completion = completion it doesnt work.

also, completion?(restTime) doens't work either, nor does setting the default to nil, as when i checked with print(completion) = nil.

Guesses as to what is happening: 
Is the first completion handler "completing the function" therefore the second doesnt fire? Im passing a nil value, as opposed to not running it?

Apologies if this is simple, google is purple and still not sure what im doing wrong.

Comment: "completion?(restTime) doens't work either".  What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies here:

```
// ... 
print("2")
self.calculateSegmentDirections(index+1, time: timeVar, 
         routes: routesVar, loc: restLocation, completion: nil)
// ...
```

When you call `calculateSegmentDirections` recursivly, you do not hand-in the completion handler but `nil`. Is this intended? In my opinion, this should be:

```
// ... 
print("2")
self.calculateSegmentDirections(index+1, time: timeVar, 
         routes: routesVar, loc: restLocation, completion: completion)
// ...
```

Comment: it worked! although im not entirely sure why. why does nil not work, i assume if i pass nil, im passing a value of nil, as opposed to not using the completion, therefore if i pass the completion in again, it just "resets" it? And thank you very much, this has cost me many hours.

Comment: Passing `nil` does not work, because you are calling the function _recursively_. The first call (A) will print "1", enters the `if` branch, print "2" and then calls itself again (B), e.g. `calculateSegmentDirections`. This will print "1", enters the `else` branch, print "3" and then calls the completion handler (if not `nil`) - but this is the completion handler parameter that it gets from (B), not from (A).

Comment: yes, this is what i thought, i just didnt know i could pass completion into its own handler. Thanks very much you've made it very clear and saved me a lot of time. I have to write a lot of these now, so will be v useful.